# updating Mongoose documents with nested arrays at multiple indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm having trouble updating a schema with a nested array to have one objectID in multiple rows of the array. Please help if you can!

My Schema looks like this:

```
var ProblemSchema = new Schema({
      data : "etc..."
      array1 : [{
        _id : { type: 'String' },
        array2: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
      }]}
```

I can easily add an objectId to a SINGLE nested array using the $ operator in the update object like so:

```
var query = {array1._id : ID};
var update = {$push : {'array1.$.array2' : objectId}};
Problem.update(query, update)
```

I want to be able to, however, add the same objectId to MULTIPLE array2s (i.e. corresponding to different array1 ids) in one query, but the $ operator only matches to the first match to the query so I can't do it the way outlined above.

I'm also trying to avoid having a for loop on the server (I realize I could find() the correct document then use a for loop in which I manually push() the objectID to the correct array2s but the solution involves large overhead), can anyone think of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of MongoDB 2.6, there's no way to do this with with a single update query. The [$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) is a placeholder for the first matching element in an array. There's a MongoDB feature request for updating all matching elements of an array, [SERVER-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243), that you can track in the meantime.